# Empty metadata for tables replicated using Google Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm using Data Fusion to replicate tables from MysQL production databases into BigQuery. It works well and the latency is low, which is nice.
On top of replicating all selected tables, Data Fusion adds a few metadata columns in each replicated table: `_sequence_num`, `_source_timestamp`, `_row_id` and, if the option was selected during job creation, `_is_deleted`.

While `_is_deleted` and `_sequence_num` columns are filled correctly, the `_source_timestamp` column always remains empty. Did I miss something during the job configuration or is it the expected behavior?
I was not able to find anything relevant in the documentation.

Thanks in advance!

I tried multiple jobs configuration but none led to filled metadata columns.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your requirements? Are you using [this](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/963543163/Google+BigQuery+Replication+Target) plugin for capturing events from MySQL to Bigquery?

Comment: Hello, this is indeed the plugin I'm using. Actually the answer to my question is shown in your page, this seems to be a known issue.
The `_source_timestamp` column is not applicable to my source, but the column is created anyway. 
Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `_source_timestamp` is only captured for CDC streams that provide unordered events, according to the [documentation](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/963543163/Google+BigQuery+Replication+Target). Oracle is the only source plugin that generates unordered CDC streams today. The column `_source_timestamp`  will not be populated for MySQL databases.Although the columns are present, they will be blank in the bigquery.

An open issue has been created for [this](https://cdap.atlassian.net/browse/CDAP-20210).